# Pagination not showing

Tags: magento-1.9

We have created pages for 4 categories in the backend under `Catalog > Manage categories`. So there are 4 categories and are linked to `2columns-left.phtml` (I think this is a default Magento page).

The pages work fine overall, and are linked under URLS: `/products/[category-name].html`

The problem however, is that we are not seeing pagination for the pages/categories. 3 of the categories have more than 10 items and when working on this issue we have selected "Show: 5", so there definitely should be pagination.

What could cause that we don't see this?

Also, after Googling for quite a bit, I tried adding `$this->getChildHtml('product_list_toolbar_pager')` and `$this->getChildHtml('pager')` to the page. The `pager` html returns nothing and `product_list_toolbar_pager` returns the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getSize() on a non-object in /mnt/projects/online-shop/www/app/design/frontend/refresh/refresh-child/template/page/html/pager.phtml on line 34

Line 34 is:

> if($this->getCollection()->getSize()):

So to me it seems like the collection hasn't been loaded correctly..

We are otherwise inexperienced with Magento and don't know where to start looking.

`Magento ver. 1.9.0.1`

Comment: I guess you have reindexed your data and cleared the cache?!

Comment: That is correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add this block as a child block of list

```
<block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
```

it look like that then the paging will work

```
<block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                            <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
    </block>
```